# How can i have a continues animation using Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

Im using Raphael JS to animate a rectangle, the problem is that at the second animation, the 'x' position resets to 0.

```
var paper = Raphael("paper1", 640, 480);
var rect = paper.rect(20,20,50,50).attr({fill:"orange"});
var myAnim = Raphael.animation({transform:'t100,0'},"1000","elastic");
var waitTime = 0;

function animRect(){
                rect.animate(myAnim.delay(waitTime));
                waitTime+=1000;
                rect.animate(myAnim.delay(waitTime));
            }
```

How can i do to have a continus animation ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael has a repeat infinity option...

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "t100,0"}, 2500).repeat(Infinity);

rect.animate(anim)
```

Its not quite clear if you want 2 separate animations (one reversing) or repeating the same one though. If you do, you can enter multiple animations like the following (think of the number as percentage passed through)...

```
var anim = Raphael.animation( { 0.5: {transform: "t100,0"}, 1: { transform: 't0,0' } }, 2500 ).repeat(Infinity);
rect.animate(anim)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/VSAED/347/)

Example with pauses...

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/VSAED/349/)

Comment: Thank's a lot !!!, didn't know that i can add keyframes like u did in the second exemple, works perfectly !!!